# Powerpoint change picture without changing cropping area

Tags: image, ms-office, powerpoint

I´ve a cropped picture in a powerpoint layer and I want to change the picture without changing the size of the cropping area. 
If I change the image by clicking "change picture" the cropping area resizes too, to show the whole picture.
How can I do that without changing the cropping area?

In Apple Keynote you only have to drag the picture you want to the cropping area and you only have to align it.

Comment: This sounds like a question for http://superuser.com/

Comment: I agree with [Passion4Code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32859524/1032586) - there's no such built in functionality in PowerPoint today. Only thing you can do is [vote for this feature](https://powerpoint.uservoice.com/forums/288949-powerpoint-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/14952546-change-picture-keep-crop).

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, I'm afraid you have to set the crop manually by "Format Picture" -"Crop" to remain the same cropping area when you replace a picture.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't much help, but Libreoffice will do this. Crop, resize, then select your image and re-insert a new image - formatting will be the same, perfect for when you want to quickly redo formatting for same sized images.

Comment: Could you explain in more details on how to do this in LibreOffice Impress?

Comment: Sure, here are the steps: 1) Insert and image, resize and crop it.  2) Copy the slide (or image).  3) Right click the image and select "Replace".  4) Choose another image that is the same size/dimensions as the previous image and insert.  5) The crop, resize etc will be the retained, but applied to the new image.

Comment: When opening a .pptx file created by PowerPoint in OpenOffice Impress, this operation yields weird result. Do you have any fix on that?

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, a picture that you insert to replace an existing one, using Change Picture, will "inherit" the crop&size settings of the old picture IF the old&new images are actually of the same size (in pixels) - if not, the new one will revert to the default crop&size so you will have to redo these manually.

This changes if the image to-be-replaced has any crop setting applied to it in Powerpoint. In this case, the replacing image will not inherit those, and might also be inserted with a different size&position, leading most likely to an unwanted result & further work needed.

A workaround I found is to first remove the crop setting from the old picture, replace with new image, then reapply the crop. This is still less work than having to manually redo the size&position (or to define these based on numbers copied from the PropertiesPane of the old image).

Answer (score -1):

Quick work around: if you plan to have multiple same size images and you wish to use change image to swap the content on each page (something we do with floor plans all the time); don't bother cropping them.

Put the whole image in and crop it by sticking shapes on top of it, which are the same color as the presentation background color, like a mask.

optionally crop the images only when the whole presentation is finished.